# Combine MKMap and Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm looking for the best possible solution  to combine MKMap with Cosos2D.

The outcome I'm hoping to achieve is to create a game where the player can run in the streets (viewed from above) on an MKMap. The player should only be able to run in the streets, so if the player tries to run off the streets, a boundary need to restrict the player from doing so.

Cars will also be driving in the streets, so the player shouldn't be able to run over them.

The best example of what I'm trying to achieve is probably a game called GTA. (the older versions)

*Example:*
[image]

Comment: Forget it. Implement your own map. MKMap gives you no information other than some locations so you can't do pathfinding, you won't have collision detection information that you need for a GTA style game. Even if you could get that info from some other maps implementation it would not be detailed enough for a game, nor is it guaranteed to be seamless (ie there may be gaps, not all info filled in for some places, etc). Plus if your map provider updates the map, your player could be in a blocked area etc etc. You need to design & draw your own map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get no information about where roads are and stuff.... you could go check pixel colors but I don't think thats pratical

sorry I'd say wrong approach.

Instead Maybe use open street map xml!?

Comment: Thanks, would you use the Open Street XML data with MKMap to get information about where the roads are, and then use that information to create the boundaries? Would this be the best approach?

Comment: you could maybe an annotation on the map and move that. and restrict movement with the xml data. don't know if it performes well enough but that sounds good to me :)